# Volvo remote key id

Tags: volvo, key, keyless-entry, xc60

The 2011 xc60 has 3 programmed keys. One is lost, I know the id number of one that was programmed to replace the lost one. But now the car has 3 keys. Is there a way to find the other one that exists so that I can remove the correct id from the car's system?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure how Volvo works it, but many manufacturers setup their systems up so that if you wanted to remove a key, you'd just reprogram the other two keys into the vehicle. When you start the process, it takes out all of the keys, then you re-add the two you have in, this in effect removes the missing key. Like I said, I don't know if Volvo does it this way, but it wouldn't surprise me if it did.

Comment: @Paulster2 Yes that would be the idea but for this it seems to be necessary to know the idea of the existing keys, for the newly made, I know it but for the other one, I do not, I am not sure if it is supposed to be written somewhere on the key?